# Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to two String operands

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Hi i have a question about some code.

Okay, the problem is that i have some code that works in one function, but gives me an error in another function. The first code block is the function that it works in.
BTW, it is only one line:

```
@IBAction func searchPhotosByPhraseButtonTouchUp(sender: UIButton) {

    if (!searchText.text.isEmpty) {

        // 2: Replace spaces with +
        var escapedSearchText:String = searchText.text.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "+")

        // 3: API Method arguments
        let methodArguments = [
            "method": METHOD_NAME,
            "api_key": API_KEY,
            "text": escapedSearchText,
            "format": FORMAT,
            "nojsoncallback": NO_JSON_CALLBACK,
            "extras": EXTRAS,
            "safe_search": SAFE_SEARCH
        ]

        // This line is the problem, if i make it in this function there is no problems
        let urlString = BASE_URL + encodeParameters(params: methodArguments)

        // 4: Call the Flickr API with these arguments
        getImageFromFlickrBySearch(methodArguments)
    }
    else {
        self.imageInfoLbl.text = "You did not write anything in the textfield"
    }
}
```

So as you can see, in the code block above all is fine, but if i do it like this:

```
func getImageFromFlickrBySearch(methodArguments: [String: AnyObject]) {

    // 5: Initialize session and url
    ...
    // Here it gives me the error: 
    // Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to two String operands
    let urlString = self.BASE_URL + encodeParameters(params: methodArguments)
    ...
}
```

I get a error.
I have removed the rest of the code from the second code block function for clarity.

I should probably say that BASE_URL is a constant.

The only difference of the functions, is that one is a @IBAction??

Comment: I wrote it in one of the comments, but the error is: Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to two String operands :)

Comment: Hm. Oddly enough, try restarting Xcode. This shouldn't happen

Comment: Yes, that is what i thought at first, but after restarting Xcode, it still happened. I also tried to Shut down the mac and start it up again :/

Comment: Well, maybe the declarations and initialisation for `BASE_URL` and `encodeParameters:` will help

Comment: `BASE_URL` is not using `self` on the first sample, is a declaration hiding the instance property?

Comment: Ooops, i actually only wrote self as a test to see if that would help, but i didn't mean to write it in the question.

Comment: How/where is `encodeParameters` defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not all too familiar with Swift but what could be causing your error is the `methodArguments: [String: AnyObject]`. In the function that works, Swift knows that all objects in the dictionary are String objects, but in the second function, their types are `AnyObject`.

If all of the key/value pairs are actually strings, change your parameter to `methodArguments: [String: String]` and see if that works.

Comment: `methodArguments`'s type is irrelevant, what really matters is the return type of `encodeParameters:` in this example

Comment: Yes, you were right, but what i don't understand, is that encodeParameters actually returns a string, and shouldn't it be that String that gets appended.
And not methodArguments.

Hope you understand what i mean :)

Comment: Alladinian, his answer actually worked, and as you are saying methodArguments type should be irrelevant, at least that is what makes sense to me, however it isn't for some reason.

Comment: Okay, i found the problem, it actually lies in the definition of encodedParameters and not in the definition of getImageFromFlickrBySearch.

encodedParameters also takes a methodArguments, but not of type [String: AnyObject], but of [String: String], so it was just a matter of changing that function.

So RPK was actually right, it just wasn't the right function :)

And me not understanding the Error correctly, or the swift team not writing the error so it is understandable :)